# syntax errors in c++ linked list declaration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

ok, so i've decided to start brushing off the dust from my c++ knowledge, and started by doing some simple examples with linked lists, but i get some errors. my Node class is **TestClass** and my linked list is **List**; The problems, from what i see are syntax related.

Node Header:

```
#pragma once
class TestClass
{
public:
    int x, y;
    TestClass *next;
    TestClass *prev;
    TestClass();
    TestClass(int,int);
    ~TestClass();
};
```

Node Base class

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestClass.h"

TestClass::TestClass()
{
}

TestClass::TestClass(int _x, int _y)
{
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
 }

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
}
```

Header List class

```
#pragma once
class List
{
public:

    TestClass *first;
    TestClass *last;

    List();
    ~List();
    void AddNew(TestClass);
    void PrintList();
};
```

List base class

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include "TestClass.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

List::List()
{
    first = last = NULL;
}


List::~List()
{

}

void List::AddNew(TestClass node)
{
    if (!first && !last)
    {
        *first = *last = node;
        //first = last = &node;
    }
    else
    {
        TestClass *temp;
        temp = last;
        last = &node;
        temp->next = last;

    }
}

void List::PrintList()
{
    TestClass *p = first;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->x << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }

}
```

I get around 16 errors, like:

- undeclared identifiers first, last in List.cpp (base class)
- syntax error : missing ';' before '*' -> List.h declaration of TestClass *last;

Can you please give a helping hand?

Comment: On which lines do errors occur?

Comment: List header should `#include "TestClass.h"`

Comment: @ChrisLaplante undeclared identifiers on every "first"/"last" mention in List.cpp and the syntax errors when on declaration of *last and *first in List.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "TestClass.h` in `List.h` before using the type.

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru That is because you are calling the construcor wrong. Also a linker error is "better" than a compiler error in the sense that at least the syntax was correct. Please don't drive your development by compiler errors though!

Answer (score 1):

Header List class shall include header Node Header because it referes declarations from it.